# Calculating Gematrical Value of a String in C# without Using a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, char

The code below attempts to calculate the gematrical value of a string:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++){
            switch(str[i].ToString()){
                case "A":
                    gemValue += 1;
                    break;
                case "a":
                    gemValue += 1;
                    break;
                case "B":
                    gemValue += 2;
                    break;
                case "b":
                    gemValue += 2;
                    break;
                // other characters to follow
                default:
                    gemValue += 0;
                    break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The gematrical value of the word or phrase is " +                
        gemValue);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Could there be a way to simplify the code and logic without using a dictionary (or any sort of array for that matter)?

Creating a list of ints like:

```
      int A, a = 1;
      int B, b = 2;
      ...
```

is no better than plugging all cases into switch. I thought about playing foul and just grabbing the ascii value for each char but that is also to be avoided in this exercise.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is "gematrical"? Also, why don't you like dictionaries? **Edit** I see, homework.

Comment: In gematria, each letter has a numerical value i.e. A = 1, B = 2... J = 10 etc.     
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria

Comment: Voting to close as this is a "can you do my homework for me?" question.

Comment: Reading the wikipedia article, the value associated to a letter does not seem to depend on its position in the alphabet. In such a case, I think a dictionary is the best way to map each letter to its value.

Comment: @DavidArno I didn't expect anyone to solve my h.w., the exercise stated that a switch statement is mandatory and so I did. When I posted this, my h.w. had been long gone submitted but since I was unsatisfied with the implementation as required by my professor, I thought about expanding my mind a little and asking some people who have more knowledge than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
string str = "Hello";

int gemValue = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    char ch = str[i];

    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
    {
        gemValue += ch - 'A' + 1;
    }
    else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
    {
        gemValue += ch - 'a' + 1;
    }
}
```

because in the end, `char`s are numbers with a range 0-65535, where A = 65, B = 66, ..., Z = 90, a = 97, b = 98, ... z = 122.

Note that the world is a big and funny place, full of marvelous languages that don't simply use A-Za-z.

```
string str = "Hèållo"; // Doesn't work with æ, ø
int gemValue = 0;

string str2 = string.Concat(
    str.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
       .Where(x => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(x) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark));

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    char ch = str2[i];

    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
    {
        gemValue += ch - 'A' + 1;
    }
    else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
    {
        gemValue += ch - 'a' + 1;
    }
    else if (char.IsLetter(ch))
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0} contains non A-Z letters", str));
    }
}
```

This will at least try to solve the problem for some letters, like `àèéìòù` (and many others), converting them to `aeeiou` and will throw a `NotSupportedException` if you try to pass letters that it doesn't recognize (like æ, ø, arabic, japanese, chinese, ...). Note that it will ignore non-letters, like spaces, commas, dots, ...

Comment: So the solution resided in ascii values after all... Thank you!

Comment: @NiviM Technically the solution resided in unicode values, that maps all the ASCII values at the same indexes, because a `char` is unicode, but it is a detail.

Answer (score 2):

```
string sample = "abc";
int sum = (from c in sample select char.IsLetter(c) ? char.IsUpper(c) ? c - 'A' + 1 : c - 'a' + 1 : 0).Sum();
Console.WriteLine("The gematrical value of the word or phrase is {0}", sum);
```

Comment: ... and only if the value associated to each letter corresponds to its position in the alphabet which does not seem to be the case

Comment: In all other cases you have to make dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can create dictionary of lowercase char values, and then project each char to value in simple LINQ query:

```
var str = "aBb";

var letterValues = new Dictionary<char, int> {
    {'a', 1},
    {'b', 2}
};

int gemValue = str.Select(Char.ToLower)
                  .Sum(ch => letterValues.Contains(ch) ? letterValues[ch] : 0);
```

Or for better performance you can use `TryGetValue` method to avoid double lookup of chars which contained in dictionary:

```
int gemValue = 0;

foreach (var ch in str.Select(Char.ToLower))
{
    int value;
    if (letterValues.TryGetValue(ch, out value))
        gemValue += value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
int minLetter = (int) 'A' - 1;
int sum = "Hello World".Sum(c => (int)Char.ToUpper(c) - minLetter);
```

Tested successfully with:

```
var coll = new[] { "a", "A", "aA", "AA", "abc", "ABC", "AbC", "123", "hello World" };
foreach (string str in coll)
{
    int sum = str.Sum(c => (int)Char.ToUpper(c) - minLetter);
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

However, as commented by vc74, if the value associated to a letter does not depend on its position in the alphabet a dictionary is the best way to map each letter to its value.